# Android. Приложение "Словарь"

Tags: android, listview

Я начал писать ученическое приложение "Словарь".

Сначала мой алгоритм был такой:

1. Активити №1. Выводим в ListView список букв(допустим, взятых в лоб из захардкоденного массива).
2. При нажатии на итем ListView интентом запускаем Активити №2, отправляя выбранную букву через putExtra. В этой активити выводим слова, начинающиеся на эту букву. Тоже через ListView.

Начал писать, понял что идея не очень. Слишком много повторяющегося кода. Я подумал - наверняка можно обойтись только одной активити и одним адаптером?

Сейчас я остановился на том, что при нажатии на итем меняется флаг, который Активити проверяет при старте. В зависимости от флага меняется наполнение списка, и таким образом мы как бы переходим во внутрь вкладки.

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean isActive = false;
    ...

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            isActive = bundle.getBoolean("state");
        }
    if(isActive){
    ...наполнение 1
    }
    else{
    ...наполнение 2
    }
```

Этот код есть в обеих ветках if - else:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                isActive = !isActive;
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("state", isActive);
                startActivity(intent);
```

В целом это даже как - то работает, только по - моему это как - то криво и не стабильно. Более того, я не представляю во что такая конструкция может вылиться в будущем. Возможно я захочу написать что - нибудь типо "избранного", будет ли эта функциональность стыковаться с такой реализацией списков? Сомневаюсь.

Вопрос соответствующий. Правильный ли подход я использовал, и если нет - то как написать правильно?

Comment: первый вариант вполне правильный, а второй -совсем нет. если в адаптере много повторяется - сделайте родительский с общими частями, а для букв и слов используйте наследников от него, в которых будут только различия.

Comment: В итоге так и сделал, получилось хорошо)
Можете оформить свой комментарий как ответ, я зачту.